# OS X Change boot driver as limited user (for bootcamp)

Tags: macos, boot-camp

Is it possible to change the permissions in OS X so that a limited user can change the boot drive so that they can boot into Boot Camp.  This isn't an issue in Windows XP as the Boot Camp utility works for a regular Windows user.

I specifically don't want the user to hold down the Alt key as this requires them knowing the firmware password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at Bootpicker?

http://www.apple.com/education/resources/bootpicker/

This may do what you're after.